# How to get one (first or random) row per given time frame (second, minute)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to get random value per timeframe from the `dataframe` like this:

```
                               Name   
2019-07-29 08:07:12.299705088  Olaf
2019-07-29 08:07:31.473063936  Elsa
2019-07-29 08:09:41.507259904  Anna
2019-07-29 08:09:41.607259648  Sven
2019-07-29 08:13:02.310900992  Hans
```

So the output for one element in every minute will be like:

```
                               Name   
2019-07-29 08:07:12.299705088  Olaf
2019-07-29 08:09:41.507259904  Anna
2019-07-29 08:13:02.310900992  Hans
```

I tried `pd.to_datetime()` method but never got fine results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for remove seconds with [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) for first value per groups:

```
#if necessary convert to DatetimeIndex
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df1 = df.groupby(df.index.floor('T')).head(1)
print (df1)
                               Name
2019-07-29 08:07:12.299705088  Olaf
2019-07-29 08:09:41.507259904  Anna
2019-07-29 08:13:02.310900992  Hans
```

If need random row use lambda function with [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
df2 = df.groupby(df.index.floor('T'), group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(1))
print (df2)
                               Name
2019-07-29 08:07:12.299705088  Olaf
2019-07-29 08:09:41.507259904  Anna
2019-07-29 08:13:02.310900992  Hans
```

Comment: Nice, or `droplevel` : `df.groupby(df.index.floor('T')).apply(lambda x: x.sample(1)).droplevel(0)`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to separate date and time into two different columns. Then you can convert the time column to datetime and get the minute value of each row. The most expressive option then would be to create column with minutes passed from the earliest value in the dataframe. the you can group it by minutes and do whatever it is you need.